# AWS - Acesso remoto à instância

Tags: linux, windows, amazon-aws

Boas! Eu criei uma instancia Linux Amazon e uma Windows, segui todos os passos para gerar key, importar e alterá-la via PuTTY, abri a chave, pedi a conexão com o cuidado do ec2-user bla bla bla, porém em nenhuma das instancia eu consigo logar. Dá time out. Via SSH (PuTTY) no LInux ou via RD no Windows. Inclui inicialmente regras restritas, agora permiti qualquer acesso full nas duas, e nada! Alguém pode ajudar? Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

**Acesso Windows RDP:**

- Security Group : Inbound : RDP : 0.0.0.0/0
- Para obter a senha de administrador do windows você precisa do arquivo com extensão .PEM que foi gerado na geração do seu servidor. O nome dele aparecerá no diálogo seguinte.

[image: Selecionar opção]
[image: Identificar com arquivo .PEM]

**Acesso Linux SSH:**

- Security Group : Inbound : SSH : 0.0.0.0/0
- Converter a chave .PEM para .PPK com o PuttyGen;
- Na conexão com o Putty, preencher o host e seguir a árvore de configuração através de Connection->SSH->Auth e selecionar o arquivo .PPK no botão Browse.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EXTRA:**
Se tiver dúvidas na configuração do Firewall (Security Group), coloque uma regra "All Traffic" para "0.0.0.0/0" que será liberado para qualquer porta. Ficará mais simples de testar conectividade do seu servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Alguns dos fatores que podem está ocorrendo.

1 - Acesse o painel de visualização de sua instância e clique na opção security group e depois em inbound e verifique se o source de ssh está com o ip 0.0.0.0/0

caso esteja assim está correto.

2 - Depois verifique se você seguiu os passos de configuração do putty como especificado pelo amazon [aqui](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html). Para utilizar o putty você tem que gerar uma chave privada a partir da chave .pem com extenção .ppk pelo puttygen e adiciona-la no putty. Já no ubuntu basta você baixar a chave .pem

e utilizar o camando:

```
ssh -i key.pem ubuntu@seu ip publico
```

para instâncias criadas com SO linux-amazon e windows o padrão de usuário é

```
ec2-user@seu ip público
```

para ubuntu é

```
ubuntu@seu ip público
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, porém já fiz isso tudo. Estou tentando por uma nova conta pra saber se é algo com esta em específico.